# Taking indesign logo to photoshop

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have created a logo in Adobe Indesign and the client would like a JPEG with clear background...How do I take this into Photoshop to do this?

Comment: JPG does not support transparent backgrounds. Your client is asking for the impossible.

Comment: Ah, OK. So what format would I need to export it into Photoshop?

Comment: Have you tried *anything*?

Comment: He needs to use it with a clear background as a software icon...Ive tried a PNG just now and that works so Hopefully he can use it

Comment: Hi newbie, thanks for your question. If you found a solution for your own problem, please consider adding that solution as an answer and marking it as the correct one. This isn't only good for the site, but also really helps later visitors with the same problem. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export a pdf from inDesign and open it in Photoshop. Formats that allow transparency are .png and .psd. PNG can be used on the web along with many other applications, and are smaller files.

PSD files are considered "source" files that can have editable text, layers, etc but are primarily usable only in Adobe applications.